# How to make Linux use the proper diplay driver? How to prioritize the drivers?

Tags: linux, drivers, xorg, switchable-graphics

So, there are 2 GPUs in my laptop. An Intel one, and an ATI one. The Intel comes with a nice open-source driver, which works OOTB. The ATI one needs the proprietary driver, to function properly (like having an accelerated Chrome.)

**I switch between the cards, from the BIOS. Nope, I don't want or need gpu_switcheroo.**

So. If I install `fglrx` (prop. ATI driver), it'll need an `aticonfig --initial` to get the system, to use the new proprietary driver.

But how could I tell my system, to use the open-source Intel, when I boot my Intel card, and to use the proprietary fglrx, when I boot the ATI one. Windows does this with ease. If the Intel gets loaded, an error message pops up (no ATI device found)... but that's it. It works perfectly. How could I do this under Linux?

Answer (score 1):

As Xorg has matured, especially within the last couple of years, it has gained decent autoconfiguration facilities. It attempts to load the correct drivers, and usually ends up succeeding. Try deleting your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` so that X11 reconfigures every time you start.

If that doesn't work, you may try the below. If you have customized your `xorg.conf`, then the below is not an option.

---

I'm going to assume that you use a distro that has `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` - meaning, you use Slackware. I think that others have an equivalent `/etc/rc.local`.

Go into whatever the local startup file is, and add these lines:

```
Xorg -configure
mv /root/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Basically, this *forces* Xorg to scan all the hardware, every time you boot up, and creates a configuration based upon what it finds. You can read `man Xorg` to see exactly what this  does. Obviously, if Xorg is wrong, then you have to drop to a terminal and fix it.

Comment: I'll try if that works. (Don't know if it'll pick `fglrx` or `radeon` by default. That's the question.)

Comment: @Shiki Oh. Well, if you don't need `radeon`, you can just uninstall it.

Comment: Got a point there. Well, first I'll have to fix up the fonts. Then comes the kernel, and finally the drivers. Oh Linux. U so silly.